# In VBA 64 bits, how do I write this correctly?

Tags: excel, vba

Is this command

```
Workbooks.Open (ActiveDocument.FilePath & EXCEL_DATA_FILE)
```

which in a script wrote for excell 32 bits works, for 64 bits gives error.

I am newbie, I maybe wrong ... but ... I had to ask

Comment: What are the values for those variables? Is the `ActiveDocument` saved as a file already? Or is it a new file that does not have a `FilePath` yet?

Comment: There is no need for that. Just put a breakpoint on that line so you can see what the variables are.

Comment: ehrm 
Dim EXCEL_DATA_FILE As String

Comment: You should put all your relevant code into the question, not in a comment where it is nearly not readable. I don't think your problem is 32/64 bit related. What I see is that you use `Workbooks.Open`, but `Workbooks` is not known when code doesn't run in Excel. You need to use `EXCELAPP.Workbooks.Open`

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim EXCEL_DATA_FILE As String
```

This means that that variable is known, but this does not mean it has any value. You need to check which value is gets (or even whether or not it gets a value), then you can check if that corresponds with a filename in your current directory (`ActiveDocument.FilePath`), and by the way, can you check if your `ActiveDocument.FilePath` ends with a slash or a backslash? If not, instead of opening "C:\Temp\Filename.xls" you might try opening "C:\TempFilename.xls", which most probably does not exist :-)

As an example: I've copied the same code, added a breakpoint and ended up in a situation which won't work either, as the necessary variables are not filled in (correctly). How is the situation at your side?

[image]

Comment: OP mentioned in the comments (not in the question) that code runs from Corel VBA (in Excel, `ActiceDocument` is not known). In Corel, `Workbooks` is not known, you need to use `EXCELAPP.Workbooks`

Comment: @FunThomas: ? I don't understand. My code is exactly the same as the one, given by the author in his comment.

Comment: Yes, sure, and the code from OP doesn't work.

Comment: Oooh, a compilation error! I was convinced the author was talking about a runtime error! :-)